# Site Stats data showing "0 visitors/day" in all beta sites and link to stack exchange timing out

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, beta-sites, site-stats

I just noticed that all beta sites show *0 visitors/day* in the Site Stats. I checked [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/), [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) and many others, and all have the problem.

Furthermore, clicking on the "stack exchange" link on that Site Stats block times out: the page https://stackexchange.com/sites seems to be down.

Screenshot from [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)

[image: Zero visitors per day]

Comment: Artifact of Fastly migration? Anyway, repro'd.

Comment: As a workaround click on area 51 below and you can see that stat correctly.

Comment: The sites list [is fixed](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4972895#4972895)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks go to [Marc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) for fixing a bad query (or rather - what was producing a plan that caused a query to time out).

Comment: But [Marc said](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4972931#4972931) the 0 visitors/day is a separate bug - so who fixed that? :)

Comment: *I* think it was related ;)

Comment: Numbers have been frozen for a couple of days now: no update in the stats in Area51.